# Best way to disable App.config usage in code

Tags: c#, app-config

which is the best way disable all app.config settings in code? I do not want to set the options in the code, I want to check if the user does not administrator priviledges and if so disable all app config settings (like internal tracing). It would be great to enable the config again at will but that`s not mandatory.

I can think of defining different app.configs and switch to an empty one if that would work.

```
 public static void UpdateConfig(bool IsAdmin)
 {
    Configuration config = configurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

   if (IsAdmin)  config.AppSettings.File = "app.config";
   else config.AppSettings.File = "appdisabled.config";

   config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
   ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
```

Maybe there is a more simple way to achieve this via code, but couldn`t find one

just like

```
NameValueCollection appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
ConfigurationManager.ClearSettings() // <- that would be nice
```

and reenable it

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings = appSettings;
ConfigurationManager.ApplySettings() // <- that would be nice
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? This sounds like the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: The app.config file contains several trace options that I cannot set in th code (internal tracing like System.Net.Sockets tracing). I just want to disable any setting, tell the programm not to apply the app.config